# Talend Third Party Libraries Installation

Tags: talend

When using Talend Open STUDIO 7.2, In order to get the needed features installed there is a need to install some independent Jars.

When downloading through the UI I am getting a lot of bad feedback. There doesn't appear to be a way to test the specified proxy settings.

If you are behind a corporate proxy, is there any way to verify the procedure is working such as jar files being saved to staging location?

Is there any way to download these files manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the jar file needed on the internet and in order to import custom jar in Talend you can do :

At the top of Talend go in :
Windows -> Show view -> Talend -> Modules

And click on Jar icon (See picture).

[image]